# Play Video on an LCD connected through SPI

Tags: pi-zero, display, spi

How can I play a video on an lcd connected through SPI? I want to find a video player, a tool, a library, but all that I have found so far is designed for HDMI display. My actual solution is based on sending frame over SPI, but is not very smooth and I have not the full control on the Hz used. Do you have any suggestion?  This is my lcd module [here there is code used for deals with photo](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.69inch_LCD_Module). I'm using a raspberry pi Zero.